# Twitter implementation on Android

Tags: android, twitter

I'm trying to implement Twitter search in my android app. I'm using Twitter4j,
but I can't get any tweets.
What am I missing?

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_KEY)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_SECRET)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

 try{                     
                        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
                        System.out.println("Showing home timeline.");
                        for (Status status : statuses) {
                            System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" +
                                               status.getText());
                        } }catch(Exception ex)
                  {
                      System.out.println("Error");  
                  }
}
```

Comment: this code is for home timeline no? does this gives tweets?

Comment: I want to get general tweets (without Login), and no, it doesn't work...

Comment: What does the ex exception say ?

Comment: @Mor Without authentication no api will work. It will throw Bad authentication data error.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I checked the exception and fixed it, it was about adding thread to MainActivity... and about the authentication: If I add twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET) it says "customer key/secret pair already set", but if I delete it, it says they're missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is `how to implement Twitter search` and in your code, your code is about `how to get Home Timeline`.

Ok, here's the **working code** for implementing home timeline.

```
    try {
            List<Status> statuses;
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKeyStr, consumerSecretStr);
            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(accessTokenStr,
                    accessTokenSecretStr);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

            statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
                        System.out.println("Showing Home timeline :");
            for (Status status : statuses) {
                System.out.println(status.getUser().getScreenName() + " : " + status.getText());
            }

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output :

```
Showing Home timeline :

TheNextWeb : Grooveshark returned from the dead this week, sketchier than ever http://t.co/8fdP1i1duI http://t.co/KcHBWNi4gD
mashable : Roses are nice, but here are 6 truly life-changing gifts that American mothers deserve: http://t.co/kTJocxz49D
verge : The official Sweden Vimeo account published a video promoting its waste management abilities http://t.co/9QyxQ5sMBx http://t.co/4p1SNZRazD
arstechnica : Appeals court kills flight attendants’ challenge to electronics on planes http://t.co/cQ5dwxoyrS by @cfarivar
mashable : Liberia is now free of Ebola, says the @WHO. But just one sick patient could spark a resurgence of cases http://t.co/Z2KwBw44kh
Gizmodo : Running old Mac II software on a smartwatch is a great and terrible idea: http://t.co/CH5l1PG376 http://t.co/VlOcRxtksB
TheNextWeb : Why you should consider taking a break from your career http://t.co/fSsBwzjlzv http://t.co/FvNMZ99Q1F
SAI : Here's what 13 famous tech titans looked like in their yearbook photos http://t.co/OBERDT0otk http://t.co/S5ExeKrdQ7
TechCrunch : Can You Fear Me Now? http://t.co/pnUiysbIAe by @rezendi
SAI : What it's like to use Kitchensurfing, a startup that puts a professional chef in your kitchen http://t.co/2NGlQ3Nhji
CNET : Serious runners, the smart socks you've been waiting for are here http://t.co/G8PUmOjvIq
ForbesTech : For two decades, investors in wind energy have been buoyed by nearly $9B in tax subsidies and giveaways: http://t.co/yqP6tp20xJ
mashable : Boy rock star in a hairnet. You go, Mick Jagger. Go. http://t.co/0uzi5EddXM http://t.co/hNkFlWve7z
TheNextWeb : TypeDrummer turns your computer keyboard into a drum kit http://t.co/kil9aUSW42 http://t.co/fgAnOUjcvG
verge : Shooting entirely with IMAX cameras will make the next Avengers movies something truly unique http://t.co/7AOCdJD4iF http://t.co/pvDah17nRn
SAI : Uber could soon be the most valuable startup of all time http://t.co/2wGI8mcgWW
toi_tech : Google now lets you order food in US
http://t.co/IdER8GRn8V http://t.co/pUWNgJZZEf
SAI : Why Facebook has been aggressively reminding you of your friends' birthdays this month http://t.co/ftgMEMQJzL by @Slate
MicrosoftIndia : Take a guess in your replies & then head to #ByTheNumbers to check if you've got it right! http://t.co/hNXhbP40y6 http://t.co/RU6nfd3tQ4
ForbesTech : It's no Tesla, but Chevy's Spark EV is a fraction of the price: http://t.co/VQGMRDbH2W http://t.co/xGJ945GcEk
```

**NOTE**

> Without authentication, you can't implement anything related to Twitter as it expect you to authenticate first. Simply put without login you can't done.

Comment: Ok, it was my mistake, I did mean Twitter search... I just added "Query query = new Query("twitter");" and changed this line "statuses = twitter.search(query).getTweets();", and it works as a query too. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Mor Ahhhh...that's nice :)